# Feature not working in Sharepont2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created one site column in the one site collection. I created another new site collection. My intention is, without creating manually site column, i created feature to add that site column with custom C# program. Installed that feature and activated. But my feature not working properly. In the **site collection features** that feature is showing with the name. But the site column is not adding. What may be the problem. Need to start any services for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Reset the IIS once with command prompt or in IIS wizard.
**iisreset** 
This will solve your problem.